# NoSuchMethod error when using org.json to convert XML to JSON

Tags: java, org.json

My project uses Spring Boot 2.0.4. I'm trying to read XML from a file and then convert it to JSON. This used to work, but recently it has stopped working and throws the exception below;

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
    at org.json.XMLTokener.<init>(XMLTokener.java:57) ~[json-20180813.jar:na]
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:516) ~[json-20180813.jar:na]
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:548) ~[json-20180813.jar:na]
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:472) ~[json-20180813.jar:na]
    at com.zf.trw.visualisation.parser.handler.AttritionHandler.extractLineData(AttritionHandler.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.zf.trw.visualisation.parser.handler.HandlerImp.processFile(HandlerImp.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.zf.trw.visualisation.shared.service.ParserService.manuallyProcessAttritionData(ParserService.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.zf.trw.visualisation.parser.component.ScheduledTask.processAttritionDataFilesForAllLines(ScheduledTask.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

The code I'm using to convert the XML to JSON is as follows;

```
String fileContents = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
json = XML.toJSONObject(fileContents);
```

In my POM file, I'm defining the dependency like this;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
```

The exception appears to show it's trying to use the same version that I have specified in the POM file, which is the latest version.

Why am I seeing this error?

Comment: Maybe you have a conflicting jar file with a different version of `org.json.JSONTokener` on the classpath. A simple test program, with nothing but the `json-20180813.jar` file, works fine.

Comment: That looks like it might be the case, I've removed the dependency on spring-boot-start-test from my project, and everything works now

Comment: Any idea how can we keep both the sprint-boot-start-test and org.json dependencies together ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case this was because of dependency "spring-boot-starter-test" that had dependency on "android-json". After exclusion it worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I am using 20201115 version of json dependency.

Comment: thanks. I got the same issue and fixed by your advice. I am using the latest version of json. 20230618.

Answer (score 1):

Following work for us, in pom.xml we exclude these 2 dependencies defining their own class org.json.JSONObject:  *com.unboundid.components:json* and *com.unboundid.components:mimepull*.
i.e:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
                <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also convert XML to JSON and then can validate JSON against JSON schema.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
JsonNode node = JsonLoader.fromString(builder.toString());
JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(serviceCreateJson.trim());
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
JsonSchema sch = factory.getJsonSchema(node);
ProcessingReport report = sch.validate(data);
boolean isSuccess = report.isSuccess();
```